# Parsing stdout of a program and killing it when done

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a program (linphonec) which requires human entry of Ctrl-C or `quit` at stdin in order to exit. However, I need to run it in the context of an unattended batch job.

By scraping its stdout, I can tell when is the appropriate time to quit. Is there a way to capture the process id when the program is started and then continue to parse its stdout to determine the appropriate moment to call `kill?

Comment: You can start your process with ```&``` on the end to run it in background and get process id. Then, as long as i remember, you can get it's output in ```/proc/<pid>/fd/1``` file which is filled in runtime. You can check it with ```tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/1``` command

Comment: Use `expect` to interact with it?

Comment: Does your program needs stdin input to run or only read from stdin when it's done?

Comment: @dibery All commands are specified on the command line, so I need to read the output only. The program can exit either by Ctrl-C or typing `quit` at the stdin.

Comment: Does your program output extra text after the termination mark is printed? Is the output redirected to a file?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the program does not read from stdin until all tasks are done, right?

Comment: Yes. The work to do is completely specified at the command line, so no further human input is necessary (other than to exit). Besides parsing for the termination text (which is "Call ... end"), I need to scrape other output text to log error messages etc. Once the ok to end is detected, subsequent program output is no more important and will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only input from stdin is "exit", then we can provide this string when the program is started. The input will be hanged there until your program takes it out (i.e., `scanf()` in C or `input()` in python is invoked).

```
./linphonec -cmd1 -cmd2... <<< 'quit'
```

The use of `<<< 'quit'` is called [here string](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html). It's somewhat equal to type `quit` in stdin manually. Since there's no special symbol, `<<< quit` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

You could kick the process of in the background and grab the background process's pid from `$!` (pid of the last process put into background), eg:

```
$ some_command arg1 arg2 arg3 2>&1 > some_command.out &
[1] 1974             # job number (1) and pid (1974)

$ mypid=$!           # $! should equal 1974

$ echo ${mypid}
1974

$ parse_my_output    # your current parsing code; when ready you can
                     # can issue the desired kill command against ${mypid}
```

---

In response to comment/question about parsing output ... there are a few ways to do this depending on what you're trying to do.

One simplistic `tail` example:

```
# run command and direct sterr/stdout to file 'some_command.out'

some_command arg1 arg2 arg3 2>&1 > some_command.out &

# save pid of backgrounded process

mypid=$!

# read lines of data from output file and process as desired

while read -r myline
do
    ... parsing logic ...

    ... when time to quit ... kill ${mypid} && break
done < <( tail -1000f some_command.out )
```

One co-process example for bash v3 (should also work in bash v4):

```
# run command and direct sterr/stdout to file 'some_command.out'

some_command arg1 arg2 arg3 2>&1 > some_command.out &

# save pid of backgrounded process

mypid=$!

# create fd for tailing the output file

exec 5< <( tail -1000f some_command.out )

# read lines of data from fd #5 and process as desired

while read -r -u5 myline
do
    ... parsing logic ...

    ... when time to quit ... kill ${mypid} && break
done
```

Comment: If there is a way to pipe the output to `while read -r line ...`. I can invoke `kill` at the correct moment.